# Where I can use Java Serialization?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

With most of the application relying on database for persistence, Is Java serialization still in use? Where I can use this feature? And do I really need to implement Serializable interface in JPA entity? What will happen if I don't do it?

Comment: Serialisation has nothing. at all. to do with the JPA API

Answer (score 4):

For your question on "Is Java serialization still in use", **Yes** and it will be always in use. Serialization not only refers to storage, but also transfer of Objects across network, where many concepts such as RMI, EJB, JMS, etc.. come into play.